# How to connect gitlab to existing kubernetes cluster using certificate

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

My question is very short: **how does the process look like to retrieve a ca certificate for an existing Kubernetes cluster to connect gitlab with this cluster?**

After studying the docs, everything is fine, but I don‘t understand which cluster certificate is meant.

Many thanks and have a nice day everyone!

Comment: You have mentioned about docs. Please attach them to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_existing_cluster.html#how-to-add-an-existing-cluster) you can find instructions how to add an existing cluster to the gitlab and what do you need to do so.

> **CA certificate**  (required) - A valid Kubernetes certificate is needed to authenticate to the cluster. We use the certificate created by default.

This is a certificate created by default inside the cluster.

All you have to do is get it and this is written in following steps:

> i.  List the secrets with  `kubectl get secrets`, and one should be named similar to  `default-token-xxxxx`. Copy that token name for use below.
> ii.  Get the certificate by running this command:

```
kubectl get secret <secret name> -o jsonpath="{['data']['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode
```

> If the command returns the entire certificate chain, you must copy the Root CA certificate and any intermediate certificates at the bottom of the chain. A chain file has following structure:

```
   -----BEGIN MY CERTIFICATE-----
   -----END MY CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
   -----END INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
   -----END INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN ROOT CERTIFICATE-----
   -----END ROOT CERTIFICATE-----
```